# Polymer - Bind events to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic, binding, polymer

I'm trying to create a polymer component that will make an ajax call and populate a list based on the response, and I'd also like to add a click / tap event to each list element to do something when I click on a list item.

I create the list like so:

```
  populateList: function(items) {
    if (items.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    var menu = this.$$('.mp-Autocomplete-dropdown-menu');
    var node = null;

    for (var k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
      node = document.createElement('li');
      node.setAttribute('class', 'style-scope mp-autocomplete');
      node.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');

      node.innerHTML = items[k];
      menu.appendChild(node);
      this.listen(this.$$('li'), 'click', '_itemTapHandler');

      .addEventListener('')
    }
  },
```

But the 'listen' doesn't work, and I can't find anything else in the polymer docs which might help me - without going outside the component and invoking straight js on the complete document, which would not be good ...... Can anyone help me ?

Thanks,
Colm

Comment: Wouldn't using a `dom-repeat` make this a lot more easier?

Comment: It would if I was populating the list statically, but I'm using js to make an ajax call so it needs to be built dynamically.

Comment: You can use `iron-ajax` to make the ajax call and bind the result to a property that's shared as `items` with `dom-repeat` and get the same dynamic result with virtually no js written (or just make the ajax call with js and set the result to a property binded to the dom-repeat.items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.$$('li')` always returns the first `<li>` element in your element, that is probably not what you want.

Use instead:

```
this.listen(node, 'click', '_itemTapHandler');
```

and if you want to remove it later

```
var node = ... /* get reference to node */

this.unlisten(node, 'click', '_itemTapHandler');
```

See also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#imperative-listeners

Comment: Polymer [tip](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#annotated-listeners): "Use `on-tap` rather than `on-click` for an event that fires consistently across both touch (mobile) and click (desktop) devices.". So, you should listen to "tap" instead of "click".

Comment: The third argument to [`Polymer.listen/unlisten`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/api/#Polymer.Base:method-listen) must be the method name (string), not a function ref. Your example yields an error when `li` is clicked.

Comment: @tony19 Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Günter. That worked. 
Actually the problem was - that I was hiding the list on blur event that got triggered on the click as well, so the click event never got fired !